# How to read byte strings generated by marshall on the jquery side?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

On the Django server side, I form a response:

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        url = reverse(settlement_create, args=[settlement_id])
        return HttpResponse(marshal.dumps({'url': url}), content_type="application/json")
```

, where `url=/settlement/154/create`. jQuery cannot decode the byte string correctly and it turns out `{� url� /settlement/154/create0`.

```js
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url :  url,
      data : {'text': city_info},
      success : function(response){
          $("#city-href").attr('href', response['url']); 
      },
      error : function(response){
          console.log(response)
      }
  });
```

If you use a regular json library instead of marshal, then everything works fine. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you convert the string to base64 on the server before?

Comment: @Memristor: well just converting it to a JSON blob makes it readable, and effective. Apparently it is marshalled to save a few cycles, but likely this is not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something is wrong with the encoder. You can just let Django do the work with a [**`JsonResponse`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # …
        url = reverse(settlement_create, args=[settlement_id])
        return JsonResponse({'url': url})
```

Comment: I believe that JsonResponse is executed on top of the json library that I want to get away from. Marshal is much faster than json, that's the reason

Comment: @RomanBolshevik: well, performance is (heavily) overrated, especially for Python. The idea of Python is that developer's time is more expensive than processing time: Python does not aim to get the last cycle out of a CPU, it aims to make developers as efficient as possible, and in case the machine can not process the requests anymore, buying a second machine is often cheaper than hiring an extra developer.

Comment: Django's JSON encoder is also "richer" than the default one from `_json`: it will for example use ISO-8601 for a `datetime` object.